# Android custom action bar with back and next button

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar

I've got a problem. I wanted to create something that looks like this:
[action bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6OA6.png)

[image]

Left icon would be a back button (I mean it would return to previous tab, the left one), right icon would be next button (it would go to next tab, the right one). I wanted also to make it repeatedly so when I'm on tab A (there are for example 3 tabs: A, B, C) and when I use right button, go to B, then C, and then again A and so on. The text in the middle would be a name of a tab. I would also like to make it compatible with earlier versions of android (like 2.something).

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to implement custom action bar.
And to target devices with lower android versions use support library. Action bar is supported only in android versions 2.1 and above, with the help of the library.

Refer below link for setting up action bar.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html

The below piece of code will help you to get more idea on this.

```
// Inflate your custom layout
final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
        R.layout.action_bar,
        null);

// Set up your ActionBar
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
```

To create above action bar, use relative layout with two image views for direction buttons, and one textview for tabname. For a better design, avoid using tabs in this case. Use **Fragments**. On each click of the images, just inflate the fragments, each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (openTabIndex=totalNumofTabs-1) {
//go to Tab index 0
} else {
//go to Tab index openTabIndex+1
}
```

I never worked with tabs before, but this is one `if` statement that if absent, you cannot do what you want.